# Android Google Maps v2 load OverlayTile from image in assets

Tags: android, resources, google-maps-android-api-2, assets

I need to get the file URL to an image that I store locally in my app. I don't care where I store the file locally, just somewhere in which I can get a URL to it.  I have tried assets and resources with no luck.

What I am trying to do is override UrlTileProvider:

```
public class FileSystemTileProvider extends UrlTileProvider {

    public FileSystemTileProvider(int width, int height, String assestsDirectory) {
        super(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int z) {
        String tile = "file://<somewhere>/background.png";

        URL fileUrl = null;
        try {
            fileUrl = new URL(tile);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return fileUrl;
    }
}
```

I need to return a URL for this to work.  I have hardcoded a file url and it does work.  However I need a way to get a URL for my background.png image.  Is this possible?

Comment: I think the file url has 3 slashes file:/// in phonegap you can use something like file:///android_asset/www/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access it that way.

But you can instead implement directly TileProvider and write your own implementation of

```
public Tile getTile (int x, int y, int zoom) {
   //get the drawable
   ...
   Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
   ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
   return Tile(WIDTH, HEIGHT, stream.toByteArray());
}
```

Get the drawable from the drawables folder with:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable shape = res. getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
```

or from assets folder with:

```
InputStream ins = getAssets().open("background.jpg");
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ins, null);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I got stuck I trying to do a UrlTileProvider, not sure why I got that stuck in my head an could not get around it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be to include the file as an **asset** in the APK, then extract it to the app's private directory with an [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). For example as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530294/82788), except using `getFilesDir()` instead of `getExternalFilesDir()` (or even easier, by creating the `FileOutputStream` object with [`openFileOutput()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)).

Another option (especially if you want/need to provide different background images for different display densities) is to include it as a drawable, then [extract it with a similar method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174399/how-can-i-write-a-drawable-resource-to-a-file).

After you have done either of these (only once, say at the main activity's start-up) and saved the file with a known name, just create the `URL` to this file.

```
File backgroundFile = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
URL fileUrl = backgroundFile.toURI().toURL();
```