# How to get image from resource

Tags: android

I am trying to send image as attachment using Send mail.
but I am unable to get the image from **resource** , but if I try to send the image saved in sd card then it get successful send.
here is the code which I use to get image from resource.

```
 DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(
                         "android.resource://com.example.birth/" + R.raw.ic_mail2);
```

Comment: `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple)` use this for setting image to ImageView...

Comment: I don't want to set image, I want to attach image with mail.

Comment: getting the image from resource

Comment: getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smiley);

Comment: Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.image); than use that drawable as you want

Comment: @SushilKumar, getResources().getDrawable(); is now deprecated in api 22. It's better to use ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.image); as suggested in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that adding a file from the SDCard works, why don't you reate a temporary file outside of your project folder from the `Drawable`, for instance in the SDCard or the internal storage. Then use it in the email or wherever you want to attach the file. Finally delete the temporary file.

#### Related to complete the suggested solution

[How can I write a Drawable resource to a File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174399/how-can-i-write-a-drawable-resource-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

It should be an answer and not a comment so I'm posting the solution that previously I commented.
So to get the image from resource you should use this:

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrwable(context, R.drawable.yourImage);
```

`getResources().getDrawable();` is deprecated in api 22. You should use the `ContextCompat` solution.