# How to save/overwrite a file from an existing file URI as of API 26?

Tags: java, android, database, performance, filesystems

So I'm using an image capture library that gives me a URI to a temporary cached file. I want to then save that file in my app's file directory as "/avatar.jpg", overwriting any existing "avatar.jpg" file. So far, this is my code for attempting to accomplish my goal:

```
File file = new File(tempImagePath);

File avatarFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "avatar.jpg");
file.renameTo(avatarFile);
```

However, this does not overwrite any existing "avatar.jpg" file. I've noticed several changes to the filesystem API such as the introduction of [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) so I'm not what the fastest/most efficient way of accomplishing what I require is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just check if the destination file exists, delete it if it's there and move the cached image file to the desired destination.

```
// Check if file exists, and delete it.
File avatarFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "avatar.jpg");
if (avatarFile.exists())
    avatarFile.delete();
```

And read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327789/4070469) on how to move the file to the desired destination. Also, read the [Java I/O lesson](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/), there are some useful tutorials there.

**P.S.:** You could also try to [get the `Bitmap` of the image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710515/reading-an-image-file-into-bitmap-from-sdcard-why-am-i-getting-a-nullpointerexc) you're trying to save as an avatar, and write it on the destination file. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174399/how-can-i-write-a-drawable-resource-to-a-file/34026527#34026527) for more info on that.

Comment: So file.delete() simply just doesn't work for me. I've also tried Context.deleteFile() and that also does not work. The methods return true but the file still persists.

Comment: Are you setting the ImageView resource as an URI by any chance?

Comment: No, I'm loading it in from a file via Glide. Even on app restarts the old file persists

Comment: Try to disable Glide's cache, that might be the problem. Try to use `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` and `.skipMemoryCache( true )` when loading the image.

Comment: Glide.with(this)
                    .load(FileUtils.getUserAvatarFile(this))
                    .into(headerProfileView); is my code; there's no .diskCacheStrategy or .skipMemoryCache method in the builder

Comment: There should be. Like: `Glide.with(this) .load(FileUtils.getUserAvatarFile(this)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).skipMemoryCache( true ).into(headerProfileView);`

Comment: If neither of that works, try: `mContext.getContentResolver().delete(fileToDeleteUri, null, null);`