# Android Studio upload image to firebase storage from drawable

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

Is there a way to upload a PNG file from my Drawable folder to Firebase storage and get the URL and put it in a FireStore Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would [convert your drawable resource to a bitmap and save it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174399/how-can-i-write-a-drawable-resource-to-a-file), then [upload that file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) to Firebase Storage, during which you will determine the image URL. You can then store that value in your Firestore database.